# Getting objects from google cloud by id and not by name

Tags: c#, get, google-cloud-storage

I need to get an object from google cloud storage.

Documentation of Objects (focus on attributes): https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects

The get method receives as parameters the bucket name and the name of the object.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get

The list method receives as parameters the bucket name and a prefix of the name of the objects.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

Objects have and ID instead of the name. I need to get an object by this parameter (ID).

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you thinking that an object name is different than an ID?  Where are you getting this ID?

Comment: I have a DataBase with the documents information, and they have an incremental numeric ID. I need to replicate a phisic repository into the cloud, trying to mantein the logic I have

Answer (score 1):

The id of a GCS object is formed by "bucketName/objectName/generationNumber" per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#id)

If you have the id, then you will have the bucket and object.

If you want to use the get method and make sure that the generation matches, you can use the [generation optional query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get#generation), you can click the "Try it!" button in the previous link and test this making sure generation matches

For [C#](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.GetObjectOptions.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_GetObjectOptions_Generation)